# Copying / Uploading files causes file not found errors

Tags: file, vbscript, asp-classic, permissions, firewall

I have a big generic jobboard system, one database, shared codebase, multiple sites and webservers. It's an old site ASP Classic/SQL 2015 DB/WIN 2012

On one site we currently have a problem that is affecting them a lot. They are a site offering jobs within the UAE and a lot of the reverse IP checks I have done have shown that the problematic user comes from Dubai/UAE.

The issue started to be noticed in that a lot of candidates had blank (0 byte) CV files. The ASP Upload object has a maximum file size property but not a minimum one. Therefore I wrote in a check so that straight after the file is uploaded if the file size was 0 bytes it would show a "Blank File" error message.

However I don't think this is the problem, thousands of people just uploading blank files, it makes no sense. We are getting errors where files that are used both as CVs and applications are copied from the candidates stored CV location are just not there any more so cause a **File Not Found** error e.g.

> Error: copying from d:\inetpub\wwwroot\jobboard\private_v3\5024\applications\CV_4115714_Job_3555326.docx to CV profile path d:\inetpub\wwwroot\jobboard\private_v3\5024\cands\CV_4115714.docx - Error: 53 File not found

Also during the copy stage from the temporary folder where ALL files are uploaded to and then to their correct location e.g.

I also get these other errors when I am

> Error: copying from d:\inetpub\wwwroot\Jobboard\interim\temp\BRAYANT MACHARA RECDEPTION.doc to d:\inetpub\wwwroot\jobboard\private_v3\5024\applications\CV_4111523_Job_3493051.doc - Err: -2147024231

I just get this error code **-2147024231** What it means I don't know but I guess it's a similar issue to the file not existing as I sat with this temporary directory (where all files go to) open and watched and saw numerous 0 byte files hit the servers. They were obviously not 0 bytes before as why would anyone upload a blank CV. They were PDFs, docx, rtf, txt all forms.

I would say 95%+ IP checks said they were from the UAE. I don't know if the Mid East, UAE have some sort of Chinese/Australian firewall that checks content for flesh coloured images as these CVs usually contain numerous photos of the people and as they are from hot countries, lots of flesh.

We have no virus checker on this folder to wipe out files with viruses ASAP so I am at a loss to what could be happening.

No other site on the same webserver is having this issue. No other site based in the UAE is having this issue therefore as all the code is shared between sites it makes little sense and does not seem like a code based problem.

We cannot replicate any of these issues from here. Even with CV's sent to us from the candidates who cannot upload them from the UAE (they get blanked, and cause a file cannot be found error etc).

We can upload all kinds of files, never get errors and therefore cannot replicate the issue which obviously isn't making the customer happy.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a server side check for 0 size file that would rule out some sort of country firewall, wouldn't it? Looking at the most common encoding used in UAE it is ISO/IEC 8859 compared to the USA which is UTF-8. Could that have something to do with it (some sort of server file system setting)?

Comment: The DB is set to nvarchar for all text and the site is using UTF-8, we have had Arabic, Chinese and other languages inputted and saved ok. Also we have had the actual cv files sent to us that they couldn't upload and we could upload them so I doubt its the Charset but the thing is some UAE peoples CVs are getting through just not all of them and its 95% UAE so other countries are affected just not as much. I will have to add in the code for 0 bytes on checking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that the folder holding the files had too many files (2.5 million), and there must have been an I/O issue either finding files to copy or move etc. We removed over 500,000 files and then it started working again. I don't know why some error messages were not being displayed but I found some instances where it said the file could not be found, and the file actually did exist in the folder, therefore it was an invalid error message. This made me think it was an issue with the OS or VBS/ASP DLLS not being able to find the files (in time), rather than find them at all. A re-design of the folder structure and a regular cull of old files seems to have fixed it.